# why wont XML read from string? (but will from .txt of same data)

Tags: c#, xml, file, text, save

this is the code in question:

```
using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("AIDA64_SensorValues"))
{
    using (var readerz = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0))
    {
        var bytes = new byte[567];
        var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        readerz.ReadArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        File.WriteAllText("C:\\myFile.txt", encoding.GetString(bytes));

        var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("C:\\myFile.txt", readerSettings))
        {
```

This is what myfile.txt looks like:

```
<sys><id>SCPUCLK</id><label>CPU Clock</label><value>1598</value></sys><sys><id>SCPUFSB</id><label>CPU FSB</label><value>266</value></sys><sys><id>SMEMSPEED</id><label>Memory Speed</label><value>DDR2-667</value></sys><sys><id>SFREEMEM</id><label>Free Memory</label><value>415</value></sys><sys><id>SGPU1CLK</id><label>GPU Clock</label><value>562</value></sys><sys><id>SFREELVMEM</id><label>Free Local Video Memory</label><value>229</value></sys><temp><id>TCPU</id><label>CPU</label><value>42</value></temp><temp><id>TGPU1</id><label>GPU</label><value>58</value></temp>
```

if i write the data to a txt file on the hard drive with:

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\\myFile.txt", encoding.GetString(bytes));
```

then read that same text file with the fragment XmlReader:

```
 XmlReader.Create("C:\\myFile.txt");
```

it reads it just fine, the program runs and completes like it supposed to, but then if i directly read with the fragment XmlReader like:

```
XmlReader.Create(encoding.GetString(bytes));
```

I get exception when run " illegal characters in path" on the `XmlReader.Create` line.

ive tried writing it to a separate string first and reading that with xmlreader, and it wouldn't help to try to print it to CMD to see what it looks like because CMD wouldnt show the invalid characters im dealing with right?

but oh well i did `Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(bytes));` and it precisely matched the txt file.

so somehow writing it to the text file is removing some "illegal characters"? what do you guys think?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
XmlReader.Create(encoding.GetString(bytes));
```

`XmlReader.Create()` interprets your string as the URI where it should read a file from. Instead encapsulate your bytes in a `StringReader`:

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(encoding.GetString(bytes));
XmlReader.Create(sr);
```

Comment: awesome, worked great, thanks! you have the best answer! but all of you others helped thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
XmlReader.Create(encoding.GetString(bytes));
```

you are simply invoking the [following method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf.aspx) which takes a string representing a filename. However you are passing the actual XML string to it which obviously is an invalid filename.

If you want to load the reader from a buffer you could [use a stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx):

```
byte[] bytes = ... represents the XML bytes
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i got "stream doesn't exist in the current context" a string reader worked better :)

Comment: @Csharpz, add `using System.IO;` to the top of your file in order to bring the namespace into which the `MemoryStream` class is defined.

Comment: ahh i had .IO in before then i removed it because i wasnt using it after getting rid of the write to file code. which is faster(program run speed)? your method or the one i selected as answer?

Answer (score 3):

The method `XmlReader.Create()` with a single `string` as argument needs a URI passed and not the XML document as string, please refer to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w8k674bf.aspx). It tries to open a file named "<..." which is an invalid URI. You can pass a Stream instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the xml content in the place where it is expecting a path, as evidenced by the error - `illegal characters in path`

Use an appropriate overload, and pass a stream - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx